# How to access the rotate by angle functionality of Illustrator's Rotate Tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, tools, transform, shortcuts

I read that when I select the Rotate Tool (R) in Illustrator CS6 then Alt + Click on a point to select the rotational reference, a dialog should popup prompting for an angle. When I did that nothing happened.

Is there supposed to be a popup dialogue, or is this a bug? How do I make it appear if there is one?

I am trying to follow a tutorial and got stuck on this step.

Comment: Yes its supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

The R shortcut is to select the rotation tool.

When you'll press ALT and click on a corner, you should see 3 little dots near your pointer.

[image: Select rotation tool]

Then this window is supposed to appear. If it doesn't work for you, I have no explanation why, and I think the ALT key is the same on Mac or Windows.

[image: angle window control rotate in Adobe Illustrator]

But you're not stuck, you can always use the TRANSFORM panel to change the angle of your shape. You can select your shape and enter the angle you want in the field for the rotation.

You'll find it in the menu "window" and select "transform."

[image: Transform panel and specific rotation angle in Illustrator]

**OR**

You can press the link "Shape" in the top menu bar and the same menu will appear.

[image: Rotating tool in top menu]

If you don't see that option in the menu bar of Adobe Illustrator, click on the small icon on the extreme top right on the menu bar and select "Shapes."

[image: Add new items to top menu bar in Adobe Illustrator]

Answer (score 1):

Alt + click was buggy for me on the PC too but I found a way to make it work:

Go to outline mode (ctrl + Y). Click the rotate tool, move the rotation center to where you want. Hovering and Alt + Click on rotation center will show up the double arrow for duplicate function. Then, Alt + click a second time for the 3 dots to show and the Rotate tool box will appear. Hope this works for you!